# How to shorten following flow chart?

Tags: flowchart

Hello I have a question concerning this example flow chart.
Here I am reading an integer from a database table. the integer can be something between 1-10.

I want to make different outputs concerning this integer, like if int ==1 then show "Hello  World 1", if int ==2, then "Hello World 2".

That's ok - but is there any technique to shorten that with i or x? what it would look like then?

thank u

[image]

Comment: IF INT == 3 it should be `Show Hello World 2`? Or should it be `Show Hello World 3?`

Comment: Make it data-driven rather than using explicit logic - use your int to look up a string in a look-up table or map and then display the string.

Comment: ah sorry it shall be 3

Answer (score 0):

**TWO cases**

**CASE 1:** if you really want to show *2* if *INT == 3*

On the False of `IF INT == 1` set the output to `Show Hello World 2`
(no extra true/false)

**CASE 2:** if you actually want to show *3* if *INT == 3*
Just put the `SHOW` box directly after `READ INT FROM TABLE` AS `Show HEllo World INT`

Comment: it shall be 3 yes, it was my fault... so I can write read int = x from table. And after that Show x, right?

Comment: Yes indeed, but it is not neccesary to do `int = x`

Comment: what if i want to say if int 1 it shall add it into the List list1, ist int 2 than into list2, if int 3 then list 3 - can i say,instead of show hello world Put INT into listINT ?